# The responses of Abdullah ibn Abbas to the two men who asked whether Allah would forgive murder

Tags: source-identification

I have heard more than once ([for example here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MT_ncXa-LRE&t=595s)) the following:

> A man came to Abdullah ibn Abbas and asked: If I had killed someone,
> would Allah ever forgive me? And ibn Abbas said, yes, He would. Same
> day, when ibn Abbas at the same gathering, another man came ans asked
> the same question, and this time ibn Abbas said, no. Later, people
> asked ibn Abbas how come he gave two opposite answers to the same
> question. He said, he sensed that the first man had already killed
> someone and was seeking a way to repent; the second on the other hand,
> had not yet killed, and looking for an excuse to have his license to
> kill!

What is the source for this narration?

Answer (score 3):

> عن سعد بن عبيدة، قال: جاء رجل إلى ابن عباس فقال: لمن قتل مؤمنا توبة؟، قال: لا إلا النار، فلما ذهب قال له جلساؤه: ما هكذا كنت تفتينا، كنت تفتينا أن لمن قتل مؤمنا توبة مقبولة، فما بال اليوم؟ قال: إني أحسبه رجل مغضب يريد أن يقتل مؤمنا قال: فبعثوا في أثره فوجدوه كذلك
>
> <sup>[ **Note:** My personal translation so be cautious that it is paraphrased and may contain mistakes]</sup>
>
> Sa'd bin 'Ubaidah narrated:
>
> A man came to Ibn Abbas and asked: "Who kills a believer, is there repentance for him?"
>
> Ibn Abbas said: "No, but the Fire".
>
> When he went away the students sitting around him (Ibn Abbas) said: "Did you used to give us this fatwa? Rather you used to give us the fatwa that one who kills a believer his repentance is accepted. So what happened today?"
>
> He said: "I thought that he was angry and intended to kill some believer."
>
> They went after the questioner and found him like that.
>
> <sup>— [Musannaf ibn Abi Shaybah](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33038/31372)</sup>